# Is there a way to put game code inside a tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just made working tabs that can be linked to different html files. I'm wondering how to add a game code to inside a tab or can you only put like paragraphs and links.

Im new at html so i have no idea how to format it to get my first part of my game inside the first tab.

Here is my code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Basic Clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" id="onlink">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="skilltree.html">SkillTree</a></li>
      <li><a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
      <li><a href="pets.html">Pets</a></li>
      <li><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="quests.html">Quests</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main_container">
    <p> This is the home page.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my clicker game:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
    </head>
    <title> Basic Clicker</title>
    <body>
    <style>
    div,a {
            text-align: center;
    }
    </style>

        <div class="a">
        <span id="cookies">0</span>
        <br />
        <button onclick="cookieClick(1)">Click Me!</button>
        <br />
        Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span><button 
onclick="buyAnt()">Buy Ant</button>
        <br />
        Cursors: <span id="cursors">0</span>
        <br />
        Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I expect to be able to put my first part of my clicker game inside the first tab and as it stands i get " This is the home page" in my first tab ( only thing other then links i know works) i'm not sure how to format it to make my clicker go in first tab. idk if its possible to see my previous question but my first question has the css tab format code in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering how to add a game code to inside a tab or can you only put like paragraphs and links

You can put any valid HTML inside any valid HTML.

Now to address what you're trying to accomplish here: a tabbed game, perhaps similar to [swarm simulator](https://www.swarmsim.com/) where you can navigate across multiple views (equipment, skills).

You can easily accomplish this with a bit of CSS and javascript, see below [snippet from W3](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp):

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, and an implementation which more closely mimics your current arrangement, you could use AJAX requests to load the HTML pages that you reference in your links. This adds quite a deal of complexity however, so maybe start with tabs to see if that suffices.

Comment: but thats just puitting in words. i wanted to link what i posted(clicker game ) to the first tab then next tabs would be unlocks kind of. how do i link code im new to this. i saw this example when i was looking up how to make tabs. i have tabs now i just want to know how to attach my code to them

Comment: Glad to hear it!